# Android Google Map Fragment 1:1 ratio (Same height and width)

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create a google maps with aspect ratio 1:1 so the height is the same as the width. This is my current code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Locatiegegevens"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        ...

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Woonplaats:" />

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/mapPreview"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            map:cameraZoom="13"
            map:liteMode="true"

            map:mapType="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The fragment class:

```
public class CaseFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Case caseObj;

private TextView title;

public CaseFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static CaseFragment newInstance(Case caseObj) {
    CaseFragment caseFragment = new CaseFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("case", caseObj);
    caseFragment.setArguments(args);
    return caseFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    caseObj = (Case) args.getSerializable("case");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_case, container, false);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    title.setText(caseObj.getId());

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapPreview);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

I already tried to use `LayoutParams` but that made the width the same as the height for some reason:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mMapFragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.height = params.width;
mMapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

It currently looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom View class extended [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) instead of fragment

then, Override onMeasure as below

```
   @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        // note we are applying the width value as the height
        super.onMeasure(width, width);
    }
```

It will solve your issue.